# Multiple file upload in each inputs using CodeIgniter and Ajax using formData and add some Input id with the files in formdata

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, upload

I want to upload files using multiple file inputs...Here some HTML code bellow...

```
<input id="image_1" type="file" name="images[]" class="file_input" multiple />
<input id="image_2" type="file" name="images[]" class="file_input" multiple />
```

And here I wrote jquery loop for each input:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').on('click', function(){
        var fileInputs = $('.file_input');
        var formData = new FormData();
        $.each(fileInputs, function(i,fileInput){
            if( fileInput.files.length > 0 ){
                $.each(fileInput.files, function(k,file){
                    formData.append('images[]', file);
                });
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url:"/multi_uploader/process",
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

There is my controller function for upload images

```
function upload_images(){
    $admin_setting  = $this->data;
    
    $config['upload_path']      = $admin_setting['upload_IMG_path'];
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']         = '8192';
    $config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE;
    
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    
    for($count = 0; $count<count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]); $count++){
        $_FILES["file"]["name"]     = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$count];
        $_FILES["file"]["type"]     = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"][$count];
        $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$count];
        $_FILES["file"]["error"]    = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"][$count];
        $_FILES["file"]["size"]     = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"][$count];
        
        if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
            $data = $this->upload->data();

            $response[] = $data;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting result like this..

```
$array = array(
        array(
            'filename' => '765c3989a0735de1fa51572231b1fa0c.png',
            'inputid'  => 'image_1',
        ),
        array(
            'filename' => '58abd40a3bbe187e5a79c48295021bcd.png',
            'inputid'  => 'image_2',
        )
);
```

Is there any way can I get this result.I want this result like this because I have to put the new names of the file through the unique IDs of each input field to another text type input..

Comment: You can not get information, that was not send to the server in the first place. You appended all those fields under the parameter name `images[]`, and the info which ID the input field they came from had, does currently not get send to the server at all.

Comment: Yeah..I know it's not sent..and I don't know how to sent those please help..

Comment: Well either add them under a different parameter name (but then associating the uploaded file, with the id, might get complex) - or transport this info _in_ the parameter name under which you upload those files, already (but the you might have to change your server-side logic that processes these uploads a bit.)

Comment: @Dinesh Sahu hey you want `2` input file with multple attribute image insert with ajax with submit button??

Comment: please show us your requirement by picture.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Ct6tB62
This link is for that what I want..